# Motherboard giving error code for hardware failure

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have tried with just motherboard, CPU, and RAM, which is the minimum I can have attached. If I remove RAM, I get error for not detecting RAM. Should there still be a separate error given for the hardware failure even if it can't detect RAM or does the motherboard's POST stop testing when it finds the first error? The motherboard is Asus Z370-F. Basically I'm trying to find out the bad component. It could be either Motherboard of CPU as well, but I'm not really sure which one of the three it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with different RAM. If it continues, it's likely the motherboard (which is far more likely to fail than the CPU).

Comment: I guess I could test both RAM modules separately. Apart from those two I don't have any other RAM compatible with the motherboard. I forgot to mention that all of the parts are new. I think I heard something about there begin bad boards within the Z370-F motherboards, however I don't know whether it is true or not.

Comment: That works great! If it says both are bad, they're probably both good and the problem is almost certainly the motherboard itself. (It's not unusual for a few of anything mass-produced to fail early on; the term for this is the _[bathtub curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve)_.)

Comment: Alrigh I'll try that. I probably don't need to reinstall the CPU fan to test (I'm just booting to BIOS)?

Comment: @SusiKette I wouldn't power it on without the fan in place.

Comment: Update: I'm starting to feel like its the motherboard. Today my PC wouldn't even turn on. The only thing that works are the lights, but they seem to turn on when you connect the power cord and are not tied to turning on the PC itself.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! At least you have an answer. (Speaking of answers, if mine helped you, please **both** upvote **and** accept it!)